# SsrReflect and setoid rewriting

Tags: coq, ssreflect

I can't use Ssreflect's rewrite with setoids. Although I don't think this information is relevant to solve the problem, I'm using this formulation of category theory in coq: https://github.com/jwiegley/category-theory.

As far as I know, Ssreflect's rewriting can use user-defined equivalence relations if a suitable `RewriteRelation` Typeclass instance can be resolved.

```
Context { x y : obj[C]}.

About RewriteRelation.
(* ∀ A : Type, crelation A → Prop *)

Instance equivrw : (@RewriteRelation (x ~> y) (@equiv (x ~> y) (homset x y))) := {}. (* defined and correctly type-checked *)
About equivrw.
(* RewriteRelation equiv (coq omits implicit arguments) *)

Lemma test_rwrel (a b c : x ~> y) : (@equiv (x ~> y) (homset x y) a b) -> (@equiv (x ~> y) (homset x y)  b c) -> (@equiv (x ~> y) (homset x y) a c).
Proof.
    move => ->.
    (* Fails: not a rewritable relation: (a ≈ b) in rule __top_assumption_ *)
```

Using the default rewrite tactic instead works (even without manually declaring the instance, because something similar is already declared in the library).

Something funny:

```
Instance equivrw : (@RewriteRelation False equiv) := {}.
Lemma test_rwrel (a b c : False) : (equiv a b) -> (equiv b c) -> (equiv a c).
Proof.
    move => ->.
    by []. 
Qed.
```

This works fine.

Why doesn't SSReflect use the RewriteRelation instance I have manually declared to rewrite by user-defined equivalence?
Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:**
I have figured out why Ssreflect doesn't see my relation. Apparently, you can add relations to be used with Ssreflect's rewrite only with `Add Parametric Relation` which is documented in the manual, and `RewriteRelation` instances don't change anything. I have tried to create a fake relation using axioms and adding it with `Add Parametric Relation` and `rewriting` works correctly. But now I'm again in trouble. The relation that I want to be able to use has type `crelation (x ~> y)` (which is `(x ~> y) -> (x ~> y) -> Type`), but to use `Add Parametric Relation` I need a term with type `relation (x ~> y)` (which is `(x ~> y) -> (x ~> y) -> Prop`. Why two different kinds of relations (`relation` and `crelation`) have been defined in the standard library?
How can I convert a `crelation` to a `relation` without getting universe inconsistency errors?
And I still can't understand why the above example with `False` works.

Comment: Can you provide a complete example? Otherwise it is hard to see where the problem is.

Comment: @ejgallego I cannot use any coqjs environment because the category theory library I'm using is not included in any sandbox, but [here](https://pastebin.com/TTzR9E8T) is my code (for the second snippet, but the rest of the file is the same between the two versions).

Answer (score 2):

It's not sufficient nor necessary to declare a relation as a `RewriteRelation`. You must prove properties that ensure that the rewriting is logically valid, the most common one being transitivity (but you often want also reflexivity, and even symmetry as well).

As you have noticed already, the setoid rewriting plugin is actually made of two twin systems, one for relations in `Prop`, and one for relations in `Type` (whose module names are prefixed with `C`). You generally use just one or the other, depending on the sort of your relations.

I'm not sure whether SSReflect changes things, but here is an example usage of setoid rewriting without it:

1. `Require Setoid.` to activate the plugin.
2. `Require Import CEquivalence.` if you use `Type` relations, or `Require Import Equivalence.` if you use `Prop` relations.
3. Implement instances for properties of equivalence relations (any of `Reflexive`, `Symmetric`, `Transitive`, or `Equivalence` for all 3).
4. You may also have to prove `Proper` lemmas if the terms you are rewriting are not at the toplevel of the goal.

Note that at step 3, if you do not/cannot prove all three properties, then you will not be allowed to rewrite in all directions.

To the best of my knowledge, commands such as `Add Parametric Relation` you may find in the documentation are just boilerplate that desugar to these instances. But in my opinion as a user, they add an unnecessary layer of indirection; declaring the instances directly makes things more understandable (especially if you're already familiar with type classes).

```
Require Setoid. (* 1 *)
Require Import CMorphisms. (* 2 *)

Axiom obj : Type.
Axiom equiv : obj -> obj -> Type.
Axiom cat : forall a b c, equiv a b -> equiv b c -> equiv a c.

(* 3 *)
Instance Transitive_equiv : Transitive equiv.
Proof.
  exact cat.
Qed.

(* Example usage *)
Goal forall a b c,
    equiv a b -> equiv b c -> equiv a c.
Proof.
  intros a b c H1 H2.
  rewrite H1.
  (* or,
  rewrite H2
  *)
```

Comment: I have just tried to use your solution (manually declaring the RewriteRelation, Reflexive, Transitive Instances), and with Ssreflect's rewrite it doesn't work. Using standard coq rewrite everything is ok - but when I use Ssreflect it gives me this error: `not a rewritable relation: (equiv a b)`. I think the point is that Ssreflect can't rewrite using `CRelation`s.